# document.evaluate JavaScript returns nothing in AppleScript

Tags: javascript, xpath, applescript

I’m writing an AppleScript script to scrape a webpage in Safari, and there is a piece that I’ve been struggling with for quite a bit now.

This returns the required text: `log (do JavaScript "document.querySelector('h1 > span').innerHTML;" in front document)`

And this doesn’t: `log (do JavaScript "document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;" in front document)`

In the browser inspector, both approaches work, but in AppleScript, no variation of xpaths has worked for me.

And I really need to use the `document.evaluate` function to do stuff like `document.evaluate("//p[contains(., 'Metrics')]/following-sibling::p[1]/text()[normalize-space()]", document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;` in the same script.

How does this have to be rewritten to start producing results in AppleScript?

---

Sample HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>
    <span>Test Entry</span>
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Safari Web Inspector output (demonstrates that both `querySelector` and `evaluate` work with no issues):

```
> document.querySelector('h1 > span').innerHTML;
< "Test Entry"
> document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
< "Test Entry"
```

AppleScript Editor code:

```
tell application "Safari"
  log (do JavaScript "document.querySelector('h1 > span').innerHTML;" in front document)
  log (do JavaScript "document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;" in front document)
end tell
```

AppleScript Editor output (demonstrates that `querySelector` works while `evaluate` doesn’t):

```
(*Test Entry*)
(**)
```

Comment: `And this doesn’t` - what **does** it return?

Comment: Nothing. It doesn’t raise any errors either, and I’m not sure how to check where it falls. It’s just that no variation of xpaths that I’ve tried has worked. :(

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour with a minimal input source that you might share?

Comment: Yes, I’ve now updated the post with a minimal HTML sample and outputs the code produces in Safari Web Inspector (where the code works) and Script Editor (where `document.evaluate` returns nothing). Thanks for asking.

Comment: Well, with the `querySelector` your code selects a node and then outputs its `innerHTML` property, for the `evaluate` call somehow you seem to expect you don't need the `innerHTML`; the text node you select with `//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]` itself might not produce any output in that log, so I guess you want to output the `.data` property of the selected node or the `stringValue` of the `evaluate` result. `innerHTML` should also work although given that you select a plain text node sounds like overkill.

Comment: Well, with the `evaluate` call for an XPath string I do expect I don’t need the `innerHTML` because `innerHTML` is a property, part of the object model, while XPath operates directly on nodes, doesn’t it?

Comment: I could get neither the more complex, nor the simplest forms of `document.evaluate` in AppleScript to extract text nodes. I’d just like to see an example of the `document.evaluate` function called from an AppleScript that does extract text nodes. Any example.

Comment: `stringValue` of the `evaluate` result can’t be used because – and this is the reason for this post – `evaluate` in AppleScript hasn't produced any results for me whatsoever.

Comment: Martin, apologies if I misunderstood you, but I couldn’t quite see how what you’re saying connects to the issue, and I may be under the illusion that it really doesn’t quite connect. It’s possibly because I’m not a real developer. I’m just able to hack pieces together on occasion, but I don’t have a deep enough understanding. I wish someone would just give me a working example of `document.evaluate` run out of AppleScript to extract the content of text nodes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen is right:  `singleNodeValue` returns a `Node` type object from and `XPathResult`. Why don't you also use `nodeValue` or `textContent`?

Comment: If `log (do JavaScript "document.querySelector('h1 > span').innerHTML;" in front document)` produces the wanted output then `log (do JavaScript "document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.data;" in front document)` should do  as well. That's based on my knowlege of browser API's like `querySelector` and `evaluate` and the DOM in general. Can't give you a tested example for your environment AppleScript as I don't use that.

Comment: Martin, `singleNodeValue.data` works indeed. I don’t quite understand why just yet, but this does solve the issue for me. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: @Vladimir, I have written an answer with the suggestions made. For your other example, I would suggest to test whether `log (do JavaScript "document.querySelector('h1 > span');" in front document)` or `log (do JavaScript "document.querySelector('h1 > span').firstChild;" in front document)` doesn't as well output `(**)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath expression you use for your minimal sample (`//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]`) selects a text node in the browser DOM and with your use of `document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue` your Javascript code returns that text node (https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#text). While a browser's specialized inspector might then directly display the content of the text node it looks like your AppleScript console doesn't do that.

If you want your Javascript code to return a plain string with the text node's value you can use the `data` property (https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-characterdata-data) of the text node, much like you used the `innerHTML` property of the element node you got from the `querySelector` call.

So

```
document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
```

in Javascript returns a DOM Text node and to get a string with the contents of the text node use the `data` property with e.g.

```
document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.data
```

Another option is to use

```
document.evaluate('//h1/span/text()[normalize-space()]', document.body, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue
```

As you want a minimal example, note also that, as long as you use an absolute XPath starting with `/` or `//`, you don't gain anything using `document.body` as the second argument of `document.evaluate`, passing the `document` alone would suffice as well and give the same result.